# How do you backup memcachedb?

Tags: backup

How do you backup memcachedb? Not to be confused with memcached. db_hotbackup is not supported apparently.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to backup since memcached is usually used for...caching. Not that there's necessarily anything wrong with your setup, I'm just intrigued :)

Comment: Adds a storage engine. So I can turn it off/on without losing data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [db_dump](http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/berkeley-db/db/api_reference/C/db_dump.html) utility instead?